# AdMob Com erro no adRequest

Tags: android

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao adicionar o admob em meu projeto , na hora de executar o aplicativo , ele segue com esse erro , não entendi o porque

XML do ad

> com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
>           android:id="@+id/adView"
>           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>           ads:adSize="BANNER"
>           ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">

Strings:
  ca-app-pub-
   1770401303076452/3069328127

Comment: Edite a pergunta e insira o erro que está no log.

Comment: @AckLay Pronto , coloquei

Comment: Você percebeu que tem informações importantes cortando na sua imagem? Tente colocar aqui a escrita e não a imagem.

Comment: at br.com.paivasdev.fazendocafe.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50)

Comment: ele ta dando erro na linha 50 que corresponde ao mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

Comment: Paiva faz tempo más o erro que encontrei foi um espaço entre o pub-177.
Meus anúncios não aparecem. Só os de teste por isso encontrei sua duvida, não sei se só aparecem após publicar o app se souber de algo me avise! vlw. O código abaixo esta sem o espaço! ca-app-pub-1770401303076452/3069328127

Comment: Já resolvi foi erro de dependência, mesmo assim obrigado!!